# How to show menu only on page scrolling time

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have one right menu on my website. On mobile and small devices the right menu is overlapping the content.

I am trying to hide the right menu when page was stable. Once the user scrolls the menu needs to appear. If scrolling stops I need to hide the menu also. I only need to show it during scrolling.

Normally we use the below function rather than this any other solutions for my issue:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('.a').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.a').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

I Found another solution for this ..

```
 $(window).scroll($.debounce( 250, true, function(){
            $('.icon-bar-left').show();
            $('.icon-bar-right-arrow').hide();
        } ) );
```

Comment: _“If scrolling stops I need to hide the menu also. I only need to show it during scrolling.”_ - so users are supposed to activate any of the menu items at the same time they are scrolling the site then …? Wonder how that’s supposed to work.

Comment: I have voted up your question,although it was set a little incorrectly - the menu should be hidden on the first screen that the user sees, but the main message I understood, see in my answer.

Comment: Have found some code from online

 $(window).scroll($.debounce( 250, true, function(){
            $('.icon-bar-left').show();
            $('.icon-bar-right-arrow').hide();
        } ) );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll($.debounce( 250, true, function(){ $('.icon-bar-left').show(); $('.icon-bar-right-arrow').hide(); } ) );
```

This was found from web and it's working fine..

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not right. Make a menu icon (bars) and show default for resolutions you need, ex:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .menu {
        display: none
    }
    .menu-icon {
      display: block;  
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
   .menu {
        display: block;
    }
    .menu-icon {
      display: block;  
    }

}
```

And with JS, put an event for icon and toggle menu. After user click an item from menu, menu will collapse.

This is a standard way to implement a responsive menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, or test it on [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/oldminer/pen/mxoxVv)

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('.menu').addClass('visible');
  } else {
    $('.menu').removeClass('visible');
  }
});
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  opacity:0;
}
.menu.visible {
  opacity:1;
}
```

Ofcourse, you need also use the media-queries in your css, but for now I just want to help with JS and give you idea to use class "visible".